# Android repeat alarm or service?

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarm

I've created an application, that calculates particular set of times of a day according to the geographical co-ordinates. It gives notifications on those times.
I've used repeating alarm to **notify daily**(though the timings change for each day, hence not accurate).
But it doesn't notify me after 3 days(i haven't observed the exact no of days) unless reset. Why is it so?
For now I've decided to use service which will **set notifications daily**, hence accurate. How do i write a service and call it?

```
public void alarmNoon(long diff) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, PNoon.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      if (checkadan(1)==true){
          if (diff>=0){
          am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+diff,
            (1000*60*60*24), pendingIntent);}else{
          am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+diff+(1000*60*60*24), (1000*60*60*24), pendingIntent);
            }}else{
                am.cancel(pendingIntent);
            }
     }
```

diff is the time differnce btwn noon and current time

```
public class PNoon extends BroadcastReceiver {
Dialog db;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
    Notification notification = new Notification( R.drawable.icon, "Time", System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,  "Time", "Its Noon", contentIntent);      
    notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.sound=Uri.parse("android.resource://net.ttct.time/"+R.raw.NoonAnnouncement);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);

}
}
```

Also the sound stops once the notification bar is dragged open, it should stop only when the item is touched in the the notification bar.

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="PNoon"></receiver>
```

Comment: Did you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html?

Comment: Post your code (how are you scheduling alarms), do not forget your manifest declaring broadcast receiver

Comment: I hope the situation is clear. The alarms sets notifications at dawn, noon and dusk on a daily basis. Should i implement local service or remote messenger service? What is the diff?

Answer (score 0):

```
       PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT change it as intent.FLAG_NEW_TASK
```

and register your broadcast in manifest.xml